# SQL inner join using multiple in statements on single table

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

Having a bit of trouble with an SQL query I am trying to create. The table format is as follows,

```
ID | Data Identifier | Date Added | Data Column
 1 |            1001 |      15400 | Newest Value
 1 |            1001 |      15000 | Oldest Value
 1 |            1001 |      15200 | Older Value
 1 |            1002 |      16000 | Newest Value
 2 |            1001 |      16000 | Newest Value
```

What I am trying to do is, for each ID in a list (1,2) , and for each Data Identifier id in (1001,1002) return just the rows with the first matching field id and date nearest and below 16001.

So the results would be :

```
1 | 1001 | 15400 | Newest Value
1 | 1002 | 16000 | Newest Value
2 | 1001 | 16000 | Newest Value
```

I have tried several manner of joins but I keep returning duplicate records. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please format the table without HTML elements? Just remove the HTML elements, leave only the text, select the text you want to display as a table and then press the `curly brackets` button. And then just use `space bar` for tweaking the formatting.

Comment: Is it really should be "nearest" 15500 or it should be the largest/latest value for DateAdded?

Comment: Is your `Date Added` column typed as an integer?

Comment: @hallie Yeah sorry that was a type on my part, sorry.

Comment: @ChrisP Yup, the date added column is an integer.

Comment: Just using inner joins won't help here, you need to make use of GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if you want to GROUP BY and maybe a self join onto the table.

I have the following code for you:

```
-- Preparing a test table
INSERT INTO #tmpTable(ID, Identifier, DateAdded, DataColumn)
SELECT 1, 1001, 15400, 'Newest Value'
UNION
SELECT 1, 1001, 15000, 'Oldest Value'
UNION
SELECT  1, 1001, 15200, 'Older Value'
UNION
SELECT  1, 1002, 16000, 'Newest Value'
UNION
SELECT  2, 1001, 16000, 'Newest Value'

-- Actual Select
SELECT b.ID, b.Identifier, b.DateAdded, DataColumn
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, Identifier, MAX(DateAdded) AS DateAdded
   FROM #tmpTable
   WHERE DateAdded < 16001
   GROUP BY ID, Identifier) a
INNER JOIN #tmpTable b ON a.DateAdded = b.DateAdded
AND a.ID = b.ID
AND a.Identifier = b.Identifier
```

Comment: Anytime :) Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a primary key column on your table that will not be used as an aggregate. Then you can create a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to select the rows required and then use it to select the data.

The aggregate function `MIN(ABS(15500 - DateAdded))` will return the closest value to 15500.

```
WITH g AS
(
    SELECT MAX(UniqueKey) AS UniqueKey, ID, DataIdentifier, MIN(ABS(15500 - DateAdded)) AS "DateTest"
    FROM test
    GROUP BY ID, DataIdentifier
)
SELECT test.ID, test.DataIdentifier, test.DateAdded, test.DataColumn
FROM g
INNER JOIN test
    ON g.UniqueKey = test.UniqueKey
```

**EDIT:**

Screenshot of working example:

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry I should have mentioned I have no control over the table structure so adding a new key wasn't an option. I've gone with Schalks answer above as the question answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case self-join would be the best, but I still don't get the nearest and below value... (may be 15400)